# UIPickerView vs. a new UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

What do you think is a better method for letting a user choose an item from a list with an unknown but rather small (5-20) number of items?

Should I use a UIPickerView on the current screen, or should I push a new UITableViewController and use a Checkmark to indicate the selected item (popping the controller back automatically when a selection is made)?

IMO the second alternative is better because:

(1) You get a glance of more options at the same time.

(2) Picking an item can be faster - just touching the screen, no need to scroll in many cases.

(3) UIPickerViews tend (at least for me) to scroll more than I want, which causes a frustrating back-and-forth movement :-)

But still I see many more implementations of UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the data.  If it really can all fit on one screen or if you are adding a search box, I agree that the table can be a better solution.  I use both methods for different data.  Something that is very sequential, like a time duration with increments of 5 minutes, seems to do better with a picker, especially if it could use multiple wheels.  I use tables as multi-selects as well, with check-marks as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that by "If it really can all fit on one screen" you hint that the user may not know that there are more options if I use a table view that doesn't fit. Well, I'm using a group-styled table view (with one group), so the user gets a visual clue that there are more entries below. And my data is not sequential and I don't need multiple wheels. Am I correct in assuming that a table view is better under these circumstances?

Comment: It is often better for that circumstance, but it really is a judgement call on the specific case.

Comment: And having a group will definitely make it clear that it is scrollable.  Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Table has one flaw: as you said, you need to PUSH the view controller onto the screen. So, you are navigating a user away from its current set of data. As a result, user cannot see anything except the list with options.
So, I would say picker is a better solution if you have more than one set of data on the screen (eg. in a form). Making user to navigate from the form more than once could be very confusing.
TableViewController is a better solution if you have a large set of options and if you are presenting it only once (or twice).